# Regex for Special Characters in XQuery

Tags: regex, xquery

Hi I am a java developer and from last few days I am working on OSB. I need to remove all spacial characters from a string. For this I tried following code in `Assign` block.

```
if(exists($Variable) and not(empty($Variable/text())))then 
fn:replace(fn:replace(fn:replace(fn:replace(
    fn:replace($Variable/text(),'[$`,:%!@#_-|]',''), 
    '[$?~@#!%:;=_+*]', ''), '[.]', ''), '[-]', ''), '[+= ?;]', '')
else 
    $Variable
```

But I want to do this in a single Regex. All these characters are not working in a single Regex string. Is there any way to do this in single Regex string?

I found a method `functx:escape-for-regex` but it is not working. Currently I am using Oracle 10g.

I want something like this:

```
"[^\\w-]|[$_-]" //It works in Java
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the regex working in Java has to do with removing the special characters ? Could you be more clear, what are the characters you are trying to remove and why they are not working in a single regex, what are you getting wrong ?

Comment: It don'r remove some spacial characters. Like: #,$,! etc.

Comment: So you want a regular expression like the one used in Java but for Oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for regular expressions to remove some characters from a blacklist, just use `translate(...)`:

```
translate($string, '-$`,:%!@#_|]$?~@#!%:;=_+*.-+= ?;', '')
```

I didn't clean up the character list, though.

The problem with your regexes is the dash in the list: `` [$`,:%!@#_-|] ``. This regex is blocking all characters from `_` (character 95) to `|` (character 124). This includes all lower-case letters! Always put the dash first: `` [-$`,:%!@#_|] ``.

Anyway: If possible, better use a whitelist. You will always be forgetting some characters. What about curly brackets?